# JavaScript Domain with Sub dictionaries matching

Tags: javascript

My code:

```
const checkoutUrl = 'https://example.com/checkout/*'

    window.onload = startup()

function startup() {
    if (window.location.href == checkoutUrl) {
    // DO something
    //call a function
}
}
```

But the actual URL is:

```
'https://example.com/checkout/?x=0&spni=Random_Number&ID=Some_Random_Number_Always'
```

So (window.location.href == checkoutUrl) did't work. What is the correct formet for `checkoutUrl`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if the string starts with `checkoutUrl`. For this to work, you need to remove `*` from `checkoutUrl`, since there's no wildcard matching.

```
const checkoutUrl = 'https://example.com/checkout/';

if (window.location.href.startsWith(checkoutUrl))
```

Comment: The `*` also needs to be removed from `checkoutUrl`.

Comment: why not just use startsWith(checkoutUrl)